# How to read a specific key-value for all the child inside root node in Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of child nodes inside a root node. I want to read a specific key-value pair which is present inside each child node using Kotlin for Android. How can I achieve that functionality.

For instance here is the list of all child nodes directly attached to the root node :
[image]

Here is the child node "azd1" which have `STATUS = 1`

[image]

Here is the second child node "bzi12" with `STATUS = 0`

[image]

I want to write a Kotlin code which returns the status value for each node, along with the reference of child name.

Currently I am doing something like this

```
 val listener = object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        Timber.d("Values: ${snapshot.value}")
                        }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        Timber.d("Error: ${error.message}")
                        }
                }
                databaseRef
                    .addValueEventListener(listener)

                }
```

but instead of returning status for each child I currently get all the child nodes with all their key-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are [listening to a list of nodes with a value listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), you will  need to loop over the children of the resulting snapshot in `onDataChange` to get to the individual results.

```
for (childSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
    print(childSnapshot.child("STATUS").value);
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but I find there is still an issue. Doing this returns null value. As "STATUS" is a `key` and not a `child` is this valid? I tried doing `childSnapshot.key` and it gives me all the keys but when I do `childSnapshot.child("STATUS").value` it returns null

Comment: None of the code in your question or my answer *returns* anything, so it's hard to say what's going on. But if you're still having problems, I recommend either showing the code that you wrote from my answer into this question, or posting a new question with its own minimal repro.